# Visual Studio 2015 intellisense for RequireJS modules

Tags: visual-studio-2015, requirejs, javascript-intellisense, requirejs-define

I am working on a React project, using RequireJS to manage my client side libraries. However Intellisense does not seem to grasp `React` inside my modules when I do a

```
define(
    ['react'],
    function (React) {
        ...
    }
)
```

How can I fix this?

I write in JSX, but it doesn't work either when I edit ``.js` files.

Comment: Definitely. Thank you.

Comment: @Louis Erm, no. That solution applies for VS 2012, not VS 2015 as this is tagged.